# Data is not saved into database or not properly decrypted after adding MCrypt's AES-CBC encryption

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, aes, mcrypt

I'm having an issue with an encryption script I wrote. I have hundreds of inputs, and therefore I used a bucket sorting algorithm as an "in-script" database in order to avoid the hassle of dealing with hundreds of MySQL columns, not to mention it saves on code space. The data is stored in one column in an SQL database. Entries are separated by `'` and variables in that entry are separated by `>`. That is why I am string replacing the final result of the encryption...to avoid producing extra deliminators.

**ENCRYPT:**

```
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
$key = pack("H*", "**64CharacterStringHere**");

$value = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $value, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

$value = $iv . $value;

$value = str_replace (">", "9Y6SnNmOBl", $value);
$value = str_replace ("'", "SxsNEpBe18", $value);
```

**DECRYPT:**

```
$value = str_replace ("9Y6SnNmOBl", ">", $value);
$value = str_replace ("SxsNEpBe18", "'", $value);

$iv = substr($value, 0, 16);
$value = substr($value, 16);

$key = pack("H*", "**64CharacterStringHere**");

$value = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $value, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

If I ommit this snippet from my code, it works perfectly. Data is displayed and saved normally. However, if I add this code sometimes data simply won't be saved, and if it is at least one variable doesn't get decrypted for some reason, even though I'm 100% sure the function is being run on each variable, because the function does more than just encrypt and decrypt.

I'm completely stumped as to why this is happening.

**MySQL Query:**

```
$new_accountant = "'" . $var_1 . ">" . $var_2;
$new_string = $string . $new_accountant;

$new_entry_query = 'UPDATE phone_tree SET string="' . $new_string  . '" WHERE id="' . $userid . '";';
mysql_query($new_entry_query);
```

In the above script, `$string` is defined by a MySQL query which gets the current value of the column which contains all the data thus far.

I'm messing around with it right now. It doesn't save at all about half the time, and when it does get saved, variables don't get decrypted correctly about half the time.

I suspect it's something pertaining to how I'm storing the IV...which is with the variable, but I don't know how what I'm doing is an issue.

Comment: This code looks fine aside from the potentially wrong way of delimiting things which should not produce the failure rate that you describe. I think you should also provide a part of your mysql code around the encryption part. Maybe there are some clues.

Comment: I included a snippet of the MySQL query I run when I edit the data.

Comment: @ArtjomB. By"potentially wrong way of delimiting things" do you mean that since the encrypted string is binary string replacing for ASCII characters will not work? What's the alternative? I have to remove any extra deliminators.

Comment: http://php.net/str_replace, "Note: This function is binary-safe."

Comment: What I meant was that when "9Y6SnNmOBl" replaces ">", it might already be a part of IV+ciphertext. So when you replace it back before decryption, you might damage the ciphertext. But as I said this is not very likely.

Comment: Why would that be? It would be exactly the same binary.

Comment: What kind of data set are we talking about? How often doesn't it decrypt? What does "doesn't encrypt" exactly mean, what's the actual result? Did you check the values before decryption? Wait a second, if this is true for the same string each time then the encryption itself cannot be the culprit - it generates a random ciphertext each time because of the IV! Only the input/output length may change.

Comment: @Allenph Take the following possible IV+ciphertext: `as>9Y6SnNmOBlgfdalisduffliasufdn`. Then you would replace the delimiters which leads to `as9Y6SnNmOBl9Y6SnNmOBlgfdalisduffliasufdn`. Before decryption, you would replace the delimters back and get: `as>>gfdalisduffliasufdn` which is not the ciphertext that you started with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like your MySQL `string` column is defined with a `varchar(nnn)` data type. Is that correct?

If so, I suggest you base-64 encode your encrypted material before storing it into MySQL, and base-64 decode it afterward? This is common practice in the transmission and storage of encrypted information. It makes your material string-safe. MySQL may be bashing your binary data.

The base-64 character set (used by the MIME version of base-64 implemented in php) includes only 7-bit ASCII characters. It includes the digits, upper- and lower- case letters, and the characters `+` `/` `=`. That's good because the delimiters you've chosen (`>` `'`) won't show up in the encoded text, so you can get rid of your symbol-stuffing `str_replace ("9Y6SnNmOBl", ">", $value)` code.

Do this while you're encoding, and skip the symbol-stuffing.

```
$value = base64_encode($iv . $value);
```

Do this while you're decoding, and skip the symbol unstuffing.

```
$value = base64_decode($value);
$iv = substr($value, 0, 16);
$value = substr($value, 16);
```

This makes your encrypted data about 1.3 times larger than it otherwise would be. That's not much at modern mass storage prices, and a reasonable price to pay for simplicity. If it presents an insurmountable cost obstacle, you can investigate compressed row formats in MySQL.

Comment: Beautiful. It works, but I'm still a little unsure what's going on. If I understand correctly. The column is indeed VarChar. My deliminators won't show up in the string because those characters are not produced by MCrypt? If I understand the other part correctly, PHP only uses 7-bit characters, and when I upload to the database MySQL tries to create 8-bit characters from those 7-bit characters?

Comment: `varchar()` columns have an implied character set. I don't know which one you're using for your data. But, MySQL is allowed to alter data in text strings that aren't part of that character set.  You were handing it binary data. You might also succeed using the `varbinary()` data type with your previous strategy. The symbol stuffing is still a nasty hack, though.

Comment: Yep. Now I have an issue where when the data gets displayed in the inputs for editing it's  stuffed with unknown binary characters.